# Under what conditions are rank-1 POVM unitarily implementable without an ancilla?

Tags: quantum-information, quantum-measurements

I am trying to understand the implementation of POVMs on a Hilbert space by using unitary operations and projective measurements in a larger Hilbert space. In A. Peres' *Quantum Theory: Concepts and Methods*, Section 9.6, he claims that a POVM on a Hilbert space $H$ of dimension $n$, consisting of rank-1 elements
$$ {\{ A_{\mu} = |u_{\mu}\rangle \langle u_{\mu}| \} }_{\mu=1}^N $$
(with $|u_{\mu} \rangle$ subnormalised) can be implemented on a Hilbert space $K$ of dimension $N$.

With $ |u_{\mu}\rangle = \sum_{i=1}^n u_{\mu i} |i\rangle $, he claims that the following orthonormal basis for $K$ can be constructed:
$$ |w_{\mu}\rangle = \sum_{i=1}^n u_{\mu i} |i\rangle + \sum_{j=n+1}^N c_{\mu j} |j\rangle, $$
by considering that the vectors
$$ {\left\{ |u'_{\lambda}\rangle = \sum_{i=1}^N u_{i\lambda} |i\rangle \right\}}_{\lambda=1}^n $$
are orthonormal due to the constraint
$$ \sum_{\mu=1}^N A_{\mu} = I \Rightarrow \sum_{\mu=1}^N u_{\mu i} u_{\mu j}^* = \delta_{ij} $$
and noting that completing this into a basis and setting the vectors as columns of a unitary $U$ would yield $\{ w_{\mu} \}$ as the rows of $U$.
He then argues that, because the projection of $|w_{\mu}\rangle$ onto $H$ as a subspace of $K$ would yield $|u_{\mu}\rangle$, a projective measurement in this basis implements the POVM.

However, it is not clear how this can actually be implemented. Peres states that, if the physical system's state is actually $K$, and that it just happens that the system of interest is confined to a subspace $H$, then this implementation is possible. He then moves on to describe a more general construction involving a separate ancilla system. So what I want to ask is, **what are the general conditions under which this construction can implement a POVM**? And, as a follow-up, given a POVM for which the construction works, **is this the smallest possible Hilbert space that can implement the POVM**?

Comment: I'm not sure whether this is what you're asking, but an easy way to implement a rank-1 POVM in any space $H$ is by an isometry $V:H\to H'$. Then a projective measurement in the computational basis for $H'$ amounts to the POVM in $H$ whose elements are the projections on the rows of $V$. That is, if $V=\sum_k e_k u_k^\dagger$, then the POVM is $\{u_k u_k^\dagger\}_k$. The number of outcomes equals the dimension of $H'$. More generally, you can implement any POVM via an isometry and projective measurement via Naimark dilation. See also https://quantumcomputing.stackexchange.com/a/26021/55

Comment: @glS I understand how to implement an arbitrary POVM with the construction you're describing, which results in an overall system of dimension $nd$ for $n$ POVM elements on a $d$-dimensional Hilbert space; what I'm asking is how this *particular* POVM construction, which yields an overall dimension of $n$ for rank-1 POVMs, works.

Comment: I'm confused on the notation. The question talks about $H$ having dimension $n$, but wanting to implement a rank-1 POVM with $N$ outcomes, presumably for some $N\ge n+1$ given the notation. So you still enlarge the space from $n$ to $N$, yes? The Naimark construction requires $nd$ as total dimension I agree, but the construction via the isometry I initially outlined only requires to enlarge into a larger space of dimension equal to the number of outcomes you want.

Comment: In fact, I'd guess it's the same thing as your question with slightly different notation: build the matrix whose rows are the vectors $|u_\mu\rangle$ in your target rank-1 POVM. Verifies that you always get an isometry doing this. Observe that evolving through this isometry and measuring in the new computational basis implements your target rank-1 POVM. I actually had no idea this construction was discussed in Peres' book. Good to know =)

Comment: My apologies, I did not read your comment carefully - indeed, you're describing the same construction as I am; I thought you were describing the construction in the linked answer. And yes, my comment changes $n \mapsto d$ and $N \mapsto n$, sorry for the confusion!

Comment: I guess my question is, under what conditions can this isometry be physically implemented as a unitary operation *without introducing additional systems*, so that we only work in a space of dimension $N$? Is this only possible when the physical system has $N$ dimensions, but our original system happens to be confined to $n$ of its dimensions, as Peres describes?

Answer (score 1):

#### Naimark dilation for arbitrary POVMs

Any POVM $\{\mu_b\}_{b=1}^{m}$ can be implemented as a computational basis projective measurement in an enlarged space via the Naimark's construction. Restricting our attention to finite-dimensional spaces, let's assume without loss of generality that the relevant Hilbert space is some $\mathcal H\simeq \mathbb{C}^n$. Consider the isometry $V:\mathbb C^n\to \mathbb{C}^{nm}$ built as following:
$$V \equiv \sum_b \sqrt{\mu_b}\otimes \mathbf e_b,
\qquad V \mathbf u\equiv \sum_{b=1}^m (\sqrt{\mu_b}\mathbf u)\otimes \mathbf e_b, \quad \forall \mathbf u\in \mathbb{C}^n$$
where the second equation clarifies the precise meaning of the first one, and $\mathbf e_b\equiv |b\rangle$ are the computational basis vectors. As you correctly point out, this isometry requires an image space of dimension $nm$, and might not be optimal.

#### "Better" construction for rank-1 POVMs

Nevertheless, if we only consider rank-1 POVM, meaning $\mu_b=\mathbf u_b\mathbf u_b^\dagger$ for some set of (generally not normalised) vectors $\mathbf u_b\in \mathcal H$, there is an even easier construction that doesn't require to enlarge the space as much. Assume that $m\ge n$, and consider the isometry $V:\mathbb{C}^n\to \mathbb{C}^m$ defined as
$$V \equiv \sum_{b=1}^m \mathbf e_b \mathbf u_b^\dagger.$$
In words, I'm saying that $V$ is the matrix whose *rows* are the vectors $\mathbf u_b$ (or more precisely, their complex conjugates).
Let's consider what happens if we evolve an input state $\rho$ through $V$ and then measure in the computational basis. The output probabilities will read
$$p_b = \langle \mathbf e_b, V\rho V^\dagger \mathbf e_b\rangle
= \langle \mathbf u_b,\rho \mathbf u_b\rangle = \operatorname{tr}[\mu_b \rho].$$
In other words, a projective measurement after evolving through $V$ implements the original rank-1 POVM.

An equivalent way to see that we get the correct POVM is to observe that, in general, evolving through a quantum channel $\Phi$ and then measuring with a POVM $\{\eta_b\}$ is equivalent to just measuring with an *effective POVM* $\{\tilde\mu_b\}$ where $\tilde\mu_b\equiv \Phi^\dagger(\eta_b)$ and $\Phi^\dagger$ denotes the adjoint quantum channel. In the special case of an isometric evolution we're dealing with here, $\eta_b\equiv \mathbf e_b \mathbf e_b^\dagger$ is the computational basis projective POVM, and the effective POVM thus reads
$$\tilde\mu_b = V^\dagger \eta_b V = V^\dagger \mathbf e_b\mathbf e_b^\dagger V
= \mathbf u_b \mathbf u_b^\dagger.$$

Note that the operator $V$ constructed as above is indeed an actual isometry, and thus can be implemented as an evolution. To see this observe that
$$V^\dagger V = \sum_{a,b} \mathbf u_a \mathbf e_a^\dagger \mathbf e_b \mathbf u_b^\dagger 
= \sum_b \mathbf u_b \mathbf u_b^\dagger =I,$$
with the last identity following from the assumption that the operators $\mu_b\equiv \mathbf u_b\mathbf u_b^\dagger$ form a POVM.

#### Actually implementing POVMs with these constructions

Regardless of whether you're enlarging the space to $nm$ or just $m$ dimension, the way you'd implement these schemes in practice doesn't change. The simple fact that $V$ is an isometry means that there is a way to implement an evolution described by it. If you're more familiar with unitaries than with isometries, remember that an isometry is essentially (as in, can always be implemented as) a unitary.
How exactly, depends a bit on the nature of the underlying spaces.

For example, to implement an isometry $V:\mathbb{C}^n\to \mathbb{C}^{nk}$ for some $n,k$, you can have the state interact with an ancillary $k$-dimensional space, because there is always going to be a unitary operation $U:\mathbb{C}^{nk}\to \mathbb{C}^{nk}$ and a fixed reference vector $\mathbf w\in\mathbb{C}^k$ such that, $\mathbf u\in \mathbb{C}^n$, you get
$$V \mathbf u = U(\mathbf u\otimes \mathbf w).$$
The choice of $U$ is not unique, but the idea is simply to make $V$ into a square matrix adding columns ensuring the orthonormality condition is maintained. Then, $V$ is obtained by extracting a specific subset of columns from $U$, and the vector $\mathbf w$ is used to "select" these columns.

If you have a more general $V:\mathbb{C}^n\to\mathbb{C}^m$ with $m\ge n$, you can still enlarge the space via ancillae as above, but you might end up using more dimensions that you strictly need. This isn't really avoidable though, as whatever operation you do, at a fundamental level it will amount to have the state interact with another state, which amounts to using an "ancillary space" in the language I'm using here. So best thing you could do is to use the smallest ancillary space that is large enough.